# Using Filtering with django-filter or ElasticSearch

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-filter

I need to filter results using whether Django-filter or Elastic-search. I've got both installed in my app. I've used tutorials from different websites but the results is not as expected.

My Model.py:

```
class Wine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    release_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

My filter.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Manufacturer, Wine
import django_filters

class WineFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    release_date = django_filters.NumberFilter(name='release_date', lookup_expr='year')       
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = Wine
        fields = ['name', 'release_date']
```

My view.py:

```
def search(request):
    wine_list = Wine.objects.all()
    wine_filter = WineFilter(request.GET, queryset=wine_list)
    return render(request, 'reviews/wine_list.html', {'filter': wine_filter})
```

In case of using Elastic Search: My search_filters.py

```
class WineIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='name')
    release_date = indexes.CharField(model_attr='release_date')

    def get_model(self):
        return Wine

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

My form.py:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea
from haystack.forms import SearchForm

class WineSearchForm(SearchForm):

    def no_query_found(self):
        return self.searchqueryset.all()
```

Usually, to display the list of wine, I put this in my HTML:

```
{% for wine in wine_list %}
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body"> 
            {{ wine.name }} -  {{ wine.release-date }}
    </div></div>
{% endfor %}
```

But, I want to filter result with a side panel on the left of my actual wine_list.html. Most of the selection, will be done via select box:

```
<!-- third  Panel start Here -->
<div class="panel panel-default">            
    <h4 class="panel-title">Year Of Manufacture</h4>              
    <div class="list-group">
        {{ filter.form.release_date.label_tag }}
        {% for choice in filter.form.release_date %}
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            {{ choice.tag }} {{ choice.choice_label }}
        </label>
        {% endfor %}
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="">2016</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="">2015</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My modified wine_list.html to render the results and do not works:

```
{% for wine in filter.qs %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ wine.name }}</td>
        <td>
        {% for release_date in wine.release_date.all %}
            {{ wine.release_date }}
        {% empty %}
            <em class="text-muted">No release_date</em>
        {% endfor %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% empty %}
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">No data</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

By understing my errors, it could resolve most of my issues as I would like to have a select box for severals of my model.

Comment: In your `search` view, you simply get all wine objects and apply the filterset. When would `WineIndex` be invoked and modify the wine queryset?

Comment: The things is that I've been using two tutorials: one for elastic search/haystack in order to index the search and one from django-filter in order to filter the search. The tutorial that I was following is https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/28/how-to-filter-querysets-dynamically.html